# Question about a limit point of a set A and a limit of some sequence in A

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I'm reading Abbott's *Understanding Analysis (2nd edition)*. And in a chapter regarding closed sets, I'm faced with a theorem about limit points, which says

**Theorem.** A point $x$ is a limit point of a set $A$ if and only if $x = \lim{a_n}$ for some sequence $(a_n)$ contained in $A$ satisfying $a_n \neq x$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

And this is the definition of a limit point:

**Definition.** A point $x$ is a limit point of a set $A$ if every $\epsilon$-neighborhood $V_\epsilon(x)$ of $x$ intersects the set $A$ at some point other than $x$.

But what if I let A be a set of real numbers $x$, satisfying $0 \leq x \leq 2$, and let $(a_n)$ be a sequence such that $a_n = 1 - 1/n$, so that $a_n \in A$ and $a_n \neq 1$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, but $\lim{a_n} = 1$? By the definition of a limit point, I see that if $\epsilon \leq 1$, the $\epsilon$-neighborhoods of $x$ do not intersect the set $A$, which implies this $x$ is not a limit point of $A$.

Where are the points I am missing and wrong?

Comment: Yes, 1 is limit point by both definition as any $\epsilon$ nbhood would intersect with the set A( (1-r,1+r) will be such nbhood)

Comment: why doesn't the neighborhood  $(1-\epsilon,1+\epsilon) $ intetsect A? Simply choose n lage enough so that $1/n<\epsilon$

Comment: I understood it as such neighborhood must contain an element which is not in A. Is my understanding wrong?

Comment: That's fine, as long as every neighborhood of 1 contains a point of A

Comment: Ah, I have completely misunderstood it. Then one more question please. If I have a closed interval [0, 2], then is every element in the interval a limit point?

Comment: The theorem is false.   To what restricted version of topology are you limited?

Comment: I'm studying the first course of mathematical analysis. I think the book I am reading is not dedicating to a higher level of topology.

Comment: @WilliamElliot I’m pretty sure the original poster is working either in $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb R^n$ and the theorem is true there.  Yes, every point in a closed interval is a limit point.  Moreover, a closed interval contains all of its limit points.

Comment: $X=1$ is a limit point in both senses of $[0,2]$. I don't see the point of the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's call the first notion a "sequential limit point", and the second one just "limit point". The second one, that every open neighbourhood of $x$ intersects $A$ in a point different from $x$, is the one used in a general topology setting too (in metric spaces this can be specialised to $\varepsilon$-balls around $x$, as is done here). It's always true that if $x$ is a sequential limit point of $A$, then it is a limit point of $A$. This is easy to see, as any open ($\varepsilon$-)neighbourhood of $x$ contains infinitely many terms of the sequence and so plenty of points of $A$ different from $x$.

The reverse is also true in metric spaces (or more generally sequential spaces, but I'll restrict myself to metric here): if $x$ is a limit point of $A$ for each $n$ we can pick $a_n \in A \cap B(x,\frac{1}{n})$ with $a_n \neq x$. Then $a_n \to a$ (If $\varepsilon >0$ is given find $N$ such that $\frac{1}{N} < \varepsilon$ (or equivalently $N > \frac{1}{\varepsilon}$) and then for all $n \ge N$, $a_n \in B(a, \frac{1}{n})$ so $d(a_n, a) < \frac{1}{n} \le \frac{1}{N} < \varepsilon$, as required.) Hence $x$ is then also a sequential limit point of $A$.

I frankly don't see the point of your example: $a_n = 1-\frac{1}{n}$ are all in $A = [0,2]$ and converges to $1$. But $1$ is indeed a limit point of $A$ in both senses, in fact all points of $[0,2]$ are.

Comment: I got a misconception about the limit points that I thought there only can be limit points in the border of a set $A$ and an intersection of $V_\epsilon(x)$ and $A$ must contain an element other than $A$, which are totally wrong.

Comment: @laviande22 No, that's indeed a common misconception. In fact it's quite common that all points of a set $A$ are limit points of $A$. The first theorem (which I essentially reproved) shows a "justification" for the name "limit point": it's indeed (in metric spaces) a limit of a sequence from $A\setminus \{x\}$.